# How to automate repetitive actions in pdf and Irfan view

Tags: pdf, automation

I am doing some repetitive actions in **pdf** 
(like Document -> Crop Pages -> select top bottom etc and

in **irfanview** (File -> Batch Conversion -> Advanced -> Load Settings etc)

Can someone please suggest what is the best way for automating it. (Too boring to do it manually :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try messing with [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/).

Comment: That does look very promising (and easy to use). Thanks a lot.